# correct approach to sum within a template in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm looping through an object in my template file so that I can access the value of votes associated with each choice of a specific question.

I've looked into different ways of creating a variable that I can initiate at 0 and increment at every loop by the number of votes in said choice but when I try to use it to increment it breaks my code.

Currently, the loops is outputting the value of choice.votes on the page but I want to find a way to get the total instead. I also tried

```css
#View that informs said template: 

class PollDelete(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'polls/delete.html'
    success_url = "/polls"
    def get_object(self):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return question
```

```html
#template : 


<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the poll "{{ get_object }}"?</p>
    {% with var1=0 %}
        {{ var1 }}
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
            {{  choice.votes }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply annotate the question before passing it to the context. You can do it by:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = Question.objects.all().annotate(total_votes=Sum('choice__votes'))
        question = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) # get_object_or_404 can take a queryset
        return question
```

Now in the template you can simply use `question.total_votes` to get the summed votes.

Comment: Thank you Abdul! I was very far from that answer